# Getting weird conflict message when trying to merge into my branch

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, branch, visualsvn-server

I am using visual SVN as my server and tortise svn as my client to do all my branching, merging, and etc. The structure is similar to below of the trunk and branches

```
ROOT
 /trunk
 |
  ---/trunk files
 /branches
  |
   ----/my_branch
                 |
                  ----/branch_files
  |
   ----/other_branch
                     |
                       ----/branch_files
```

When I try to do a merge of my_branch with other_branch using the range of revisions I get the following error, `The last merge operation tried to replace the directory ", but the directory was already edited.` Then the options I have for the conflict are: `"Accept current working copy state (mark as resolved)"; :Postpone all remaining conflicts"; "Resolve later"; "abort merge"` and no matter which ever option I select the merge never completes. How may I go about solving this conflict?

Comment: Does it actually say 'replace the directory ",' or did you omit the folder name for privacy?

Comment: that is what is actually says. I know it has me scratching my head as well.

Comment: I am getting the same message - it is not clear which it is going to keep or what it's going to do.

Comment: Same problem, no idea what it's going to do, what action it will take.

Comment: I am getting the same problem and have no idea what to do